# How to create team chats

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently trying to create team chats for different teams, but the `/team` command does not exist in 1.12.2 which, is the version i am trying to do this in.

I want there to be a radio option, have people on another team not be able to see that team's chat, and a lot more configurable stuff. Again this is all in Minecraft 1.12.2 java edition.

Comment: The `/team` command does exist in 1.12, it's just `/scoreboard teams` instead of `/team`. The syntax is also slightly different, check out [this](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard?oldid=1248561) page for more detail.

Comment: But I don't think that team chats are possible yet, especially in old versions like 1.12 or below.

Comment: can you make it so 1 team can not see another teams chat then?

Comment: Well, you can't divide the chat into separate teams. That's for sure.

Comment: dang it... proximity? ik prob not but i wanna be sure